# Calculate time spent in active or visible div (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have multiple full page div's but only visible one at a time (online exam application site) or one question displayed at a time. I want to calculate time (seconds) spent on each question or div with **javascript**. Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: yes ... Javascript has a Date object with millisecond timing

Comment: can you please guide me how to do so ?

Comment: I'll make some suggestions about the *online exam application site* code you have already created - pointless to give you an answer that doesn't fit with the code you've already written - doesn't meany you need to post the whole enchilada, just a minimal example showing where you are having troubles adding the timing functions will be adequate

Comment: Presumably you have some existing code that hides the previous question and shows the next one. That code could set a variable to the current time, so then next time it can check that variable.

Answer (score 0):

A more better approach would be to use the Console API's. You can define javascript function that will be triggered when a question becomes active. You will have to use

```
console.time(label)
```

where, label is the name of the timer. This will start the timer. And, when the user, moves on to the next question, you can call

```
console.timeEnd(label)
```

, here the label is the same label that you previously defined for the above timer. This will give you exactly, how much time (in milliseconds), it took for the user to solve that particular function.